# jqgrid - jquery select row and modify href

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a problem by jquery for select row.
I  select the row and then click in the link .
But I have a more link. I thought I read href and add id row.

```
example:
link1.php?id=30 for link1 (30= id row select by jqgrid)
link2.php?id=30 for link2
link3.php?id=30 for link3 
etc.. etc..
```

if I select one row and click in the link my code working!

But the problem is when I select multiple times one row,because href is added to the previous...

so if I select another rows:

```
link2.php?id=3030 (double same row) 
link2.php?id=302060 (three row: 30+20+60)
```

how can I remove the id of the previous row?
Thanks you!

```
onSelectRow: function(id) {

            var _href = ($(".vai_ponte").attr("href"))+id;

            $(".vai_ponte").attr("href", _href);

        },
```

....
....

```
jQuery(".vai_ponte").click(function() {
        var selr = jQuery('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
        if (selr)
        {

            return true;

        }
        else
            alert(" Errore! Before you select  row!");
        return false;
    });
```

....
....

```
 <a class="vai_ponte" title="sample1" alt="sample1" href="link1.php?id=">
    <span  class="forum_icon forum_button">GO sample1</span> </a>
<a class="vai_ponte" title="sample2" alt="sample2" href="link2.php?id=">
    <span  class="forum_icon forum_button">Go Sample2</span> </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var _href = ($(".vai_ponte").attr("href"));
_href = _href.substring(0, _href.indexOf('?')) + '?id=' + id;
$(".vai_ponte").attr("href", _href);
```